# How can I split "lastname, firstname" into separate strings?

Tags: regex, perl

Whats the best way to separate the string, "Parisi, Kenneth" into "Kenneth" and "Parisi"?

I am still learning how to parse strings with these regular expressions, but not too familiar with how to set vars equal to the matched string & output of the matched (or mismatched) string.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
my ($lname, $fname) = split(/,\s*/, $fullname, 2);
```

Note the third argument, which limits the results to two.  Not strictly required but a good practice nonetheless imho.

Comment: ... assuming every name from input is in the last, first format. If the comma is missing, won't $fname be undefined?

Comment: @aardvark: Yes, but garbage in, garbage out.  OP doesn't mention this as a requirement.

Comment: Good call.  Never regex when a split will do.

Comment: @Robert: at the risk of being pedantic, the first arg to split is a regex. :-)

Comment: If there's more than one comma, you've lost part of the name.

Comment: @bart: again, garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @bart: but probably worth adding the limit arg.  It's good to use it as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick for names without unicode characters:

```
my ($lname,$fname) = ($1,$2) if $var =~ /([a-z]+),\s+([a-z]+)/i;
```

To break it down:

- `([a-z]+)` match a series of characters and assign it to the first group $1
- `,` match a comma
- `\s+` match one or more spaces (if spaces are optional, change the + to *)
- `([a-z]+)` match a series of characters and assign it to the second group $2
- `i` case insensitive match

You can change the character class [a-z] to include characters you think are valid for names.

Comment: [a-z] can include all valid name characters.

Comment: Yeah, PhiLho is right in this case and I actually do have instances of last names in both of those formats he exampled.

Comment: Oh but thanks for the breakdown.. Thats what I really needed the most help on.

Comment: If you have non-alpha characters in the names, you can add then to the matching pattern: ([a-z'-]+)

Comment: cool thanks.. Ill keep that in mind if i run into a special case name and need to switch or add code

Comment: Both ' and - are valid name characters (eg O'Reilly, Drake-Brockman)

Comment: Some last names even contain spaces.

Comment: And depending on how you validate your inputs, someone might even try some unicode to represent their own name more correctly.

Comment: Try unicode? If you are working with names and don't support more characters than simply [a-z] your code is badly broken.

Comment: @Manni, yes and as has been stated at least 3 times, [a-z] is simply an example character class, which can be replaced with whatever the user requires. The OP requested for info on regex grouping, hence my response. In addition, no specific requirements were stated.